# RC машинка,как вычислить необходимое расстояние между колесами

Tags: arduino, робототехника

Делаю Rc машинку с помощью ардуино и появилась проблема при попытке постройки прототипа)
У машинки максимально простое строение : 4 колеса и 4 dc мотора напрямую подключенные к колёсам, тоесть поворачивать машинка будет как танк xD ( вращая левые и правые колёса в противоположные стороны если стоит на месте, либо замедляя одну из передних колёс если поворачивается на ходу )

тут и появилась проблемы : какое расстояние должно быть между колёсами и какая должна быть ширина у машинки чтобы не было проблем с поворотами? красные линии на картинке) может быть какие нибудь формулы... буду благодарен за любую информацию ибо гугление не дало результатов, заранее спасибо)[image: примерная схема]

Comment: Будущее уже скоро :)

Comment: *"буду благодарен за любую информацию ибо гугление не дало результатов"* — готовых проектов RC машин + arduino — море, [пример](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-RC-car-for-beginners-Android-control-over-/). Тройка случайных ссылок: Связанный вопрос [Formula for controlling the movement of a tank-like vehicle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/125099/4279) Вот калькулятор, чтобы [подобрать размер колёс](http://www.robotshop.com/blog/en/drive-motor-sizing-tool-9698).  Вот аналитическая модель [как танки в грязи поворачиваются](https://goo.gl/7HYQCZ) — тема интересная

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

Возьмите любую реальную машину -> замерьте интересующие Вас параметры -> пропорционально уменьшите для вашей машинки. А при замерах отталкивайтесь от известных параметров -> например от колес (коэффициент пропорциональности -> отношение размеров колес Вашей машинки к размерам колес выбранного реального образца)

Comment: Только лучше не машину брать, а [bobcat (который трактор)](http://www.bobcat-s175.ru/images/bobcat_s175.jpg), т.к. он AFAIR именно таким способом поворачивает, как у автора. Чертёж с размерами даже готовый есть (по ссылке).